# StanfordNLP: Unable to identify Date with 7-class-ner

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanfordNLP to get date entities from text. Here's the code that i tried:-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;

public class StanfordNLP_POC
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String classifierPath = "src//main//resources//classifiers//english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

        String inputString = "Appointment Facility: ABC Medicine Clinic 05/07/2020 Progress Notes: Niel Armstrong, DO Current Medications Reason for Appointment";

        AbstractSequenceClassifier classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(classifierPath);

        List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(inputString);

        System.out.println(out.toString());

        for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out)
        {
            for (CoreLabel word : sentence)
            {

                if (word.getString(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class).equals("O"))
                    continue;
                System.out.println(word.word() + " = " + word.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I didn't get why it's not extracting Date even though it's very clearly identifiable in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full pipeline.  Here is an example that finds the date.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class DateExtractionExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Appointment Facility: ABC Medicine Clinic 05/07/2020 Progress Notes: Niel Arrmstrong, DO Current " +
        "Medications Reason For Appointment";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    CoreDocument doc = pipeline.processToCoreDocument(text);
    List<CoreEntityMention> dates = doc.entityMentions().stream().filter(em -> em.entityType().equals("DATE")).collect(
        Collectors.toList());
    System.err.println(dates);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working to extract this Date which is provided in example. But can you please specify the difference between NER and full pipe in terms of working why it gives different results for the same text with the same model? Is this difference also impact on custom NER model?

Comment: The full pipeline also uses SUTime which is a rule based mechanism for identifying dates and other temporal expressions.